# How to calculate the glide distance?

Tags: aircraft-performance

Can somebody please explain how I go about this problem?

A Cessna 172S is flying at 9842.52 ft from the ground and the engines stop producing power.

If the aircraft is in a glide configuration and the best (quickest) rate of descent recommended is 3.4 m/s (800 ft/min) at a speed of 68 KIAS. What is the maximum range that can be reached?

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Is there a formula to calculate ground distance traveled given rate of climb and true airspeed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37721/14897)

Comment: "and the engines" well, engine.  Is this a no-wind situation as well? Head will reduce the range, tail will enhance, crosswind might do either depending on the direction.   Assume no wind. 9842ft/800 ft/min = so many minutes of flying time. Minutes of flying time x 68 knots (1.15 miles/hours) = number of miles you can go. Do the math.

Comment: 9842.52 feet is bizarrely specific! Oh, wait, that's 3000 meters.

Comment: You really want the quickest rate of descent?  I'd expect that is a straight-vertical descent powered by gravity (aka, a nose-dive), with a total glide-distance of about Zero.

Comment: "Best rate of descent" is "slowest" not "quickest"

Answer (score 2):

#### Basic Math:

How long will the plane be in the air?

$\frac{9842.52 ft\ \text{AGL}}{800\ fpm} = 12\ \text{minutes}$

---

How far will the plane go in 12 minutes?
$68kts \cdot \frac{12\ minutes}{60\ min/hr} = 13\ \text{NM}$

***Assumptions***

- Assuming no tail wind or head wind, so that KIAS relates to actual ground-speed.
- Approximating that 68 KIAS is the ground-speed, when it is in fact the slant-distance speed.   If you need a precise answer, apply the Pythagorean Theorem to refine the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@abelenky's answer is correct if you're on the ground and therefore have time to look up figures and do the math.  If you're in the air, the [rule of thumb for light aircraft](https://www.faa.gov/news/safety_briefing/2018/media/SE_Topic_18-05.pdf) (with a typical glide ratio of 8:1) is 1.5nm per 1,000ft AGL, after subtracting 1,000ft or so for flying a pattern around your landing site.  Rounding 9,842ft to 10,000ft, that gives a gliding range of 9×1.5=13.5nm, which is close enough in an emergency.

Note that the Vg (if any) given in your POH assumes max gross weight; if you're lighter, your best glide speed decreases and your gliding range increases.  And of course, that all assumes no wind, which is unlikely in the real world; you'll generally want to glide downwind (to maximize range) and then do a 180 to land with a headwind, which is covered by the 1000ft subtracted above for the pattern.